# Bipartite graph is axiomatizable in FO.

Tags: first-order-logic

The class of bipartite graph in logic is axiomatizable. That's a fact.

So, it means that the following reasoning is incorrect:

We'll show that there exists a winning strategy for player 2 in Ehrenfeucht-Fraise's game.

Let's take a two structures:
[image]

$k$ is a number of runds. The first one is not bipartite- it has a odd number of vertices. The second one is an infinite graph- it is bipartie because of it easy to point 2-coloring function. It is easy to point strategy when in every $k-$rund EF game II player wins.

### What is wrong?

---

@Noah, thanks
I would like to ask question to your answer.

Obviously you are right:

> there's no reason to believe that any one of these Gs is a model of
>   the whole set of axioms describing the bipartite graphs.

Let $K $ be a class of structures. Let $A$ be a independent structure on $k$ and $A \not \in K$. Let $B \in K$ depends on $k$ where $k$ is number of runds. Let's assume that we have always a such strategy that a duplicator wins. But, we can also conclude that it doesn't mean that $K$ is not axiomatizable, right? Because, for any $B_k$ it is truth that $B_k \equiv_k A$  but, perhaps, there exists $(k+1)-$rund game in which spoiler wins. Right?

> there's no reason to believe that any one of these Gs is a model of
>   the whole set of axioms describing the bipartite graphs.

When we can belive by using E-F games?

---

> If for each $M \in \mathbb{K}$ there is some $N \not \in \mathbb{K}$ such that Duplicator wins the
>   length-n(*) game, then $\mathbb{K}$ is not axiomatizable by $k$-quantifier formulas;
>   in particular, if this is true for every $k$ (as in the case of
>   $\mathbb{K}=${bipartite graphs}), then $\mathbb{K}$ is not finitely axiomatizable. Note
>   that $k$ may still be axiomatizable - e.g. {bipartite graphs} is
>   axiomatizable via the axioms

1. > If for **each** $M \in \mathbb{K}$ there is some $N \not \in \mathbb{K}$
   >   such that Duplicator wins the...

Why **each**? It is enough we show that one structure from $\mathbb{K}$ cannot be distinguished from structure $S \not \in \mathbb{K}$ by the $k$-quanitifer formula for every $k$.

2. > is not **finitely** axiomatizable

Why finitely? You show that for **every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So, for every formulas. Probably, the reason is the fact that an axiomatizaion can be $ > \aleph_0$

3. So how to show with E-F games that the class is not *axiomatizable* ( not finitely axiomatizable?)

You did a mess in my head, again... Thanks! :)

Comment: Quite right, the $n$ should be a $k$; I fixed it. I think you didn't finish your edit, though  . . .

Comment: Yes, I didn't finish, I will in the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's wrong; but I think you are missing the distinction between *axiomatizable* and *finitely axiomatizable*.

Let $Z$ be the graph on the right. What you've shown is that, *for each $k$*, there is a non-bipartite graph $G$ with $G\equiv_kZ$ (where "$\equiv_k$" means that Duplicator has a winning strategy in the $k$-round EF-game). But as $k$ changes, we have to change $G$ too! So there's no contradiction - there's no reason to believe that any one of these $G$s is a model of the *whole* set of axioms describing the bipartite graphs.

What's going on here is that the class of bipartite graphs, though axiomatizable, is not *finitely axiomatizable* - for any finite set $\Delta$ of sentences true of every bipartite graph, there is a non-bipartite graph $G$ with $G\models \Delta$. Interestingly, there's a compactness result here:

> If a class $\mathcal{C}$ of structures is axiomatizable but not finitely axiomatizable, then its complement is not axiomatizable.

Put another way:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^c$ are each axiomatizable, then they are each *finitely* axiomatizable.

Proof: Suppose $\Gamma_0$ axiomatizes $\mathcal{C}$ and $\Gamma_1$ axiomatizes $\mathcal{C}^c$. Consider the theory $T=\Gamma_0\cup\Gamma_1$. $T$ is inconsistent, so there are finite $\Delta_i\subseteq\Gamma_i$ such that $\Delta_0\cup\Delta_1$ is inconsistent. But then - since $\Delta_0$ is true in every structure in $\mathcal{C}$ - every model of $\Delta_1$ is in $\mathcal{C}^c$! And since $\Delta_1\subseteq\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_1$ axiomatizes $\mathcal{C}^c$, every structure in $\mathcal{C}^c$ is a model of $\Delta_1$. So $\Delta_1$ axiomatizes $\mathcal{C}^c$. Similarly, $\Delta_0$ axiomatizes $\mathcal{C}$.

---

EDIT: The following is a response to the OP's edit:

- If Duplicator wins the $k$-round EF game between $A$ and $B$, then $A\equiv_k B$ - they agree on $k$-quantifer formulas. (Strictly speaking this only works for relational languages, like graphs - a bit of work needs to be brought into things to make it true on the nose for functional languages, like rings.)
- In particular, if Duplicator wins *each* finite-length game, then $A\equiv B$. Note that this gives us a *single game* characterization of elementary equivalence: Spoiler plays some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and then Spoiler and Duplicator play the $n$-length game as usual.
- If for each $M\in\mathbb{K}$ there is some $N\not\in\mathbb{K}$ such that Duplicator wins the length-$k$ game, then $\mathbb{K}$ *is not axiomatizable by $k$-quantifier formulas*; in particular, if this is true for *every* $k$ (as in the case of $\mathbb{K}=\{$bipartite graphs$\}$), then $\mathbb{K}$ is not *finitely axiomatizable*. Note that $k$ may still be axiomatizable - e.g. $\{$bipartite graphs$\}$ is axiomatizable via the axioms $$\psi_k\equiv\mbox{"There is no cycle of length $2k+1$},$$ but $\varphi_k$ is a $(2k+1)$-quantifier sentence, so it's no surprise that $\{$bipartite graphs$\}$ has no *finite "depth"* axiomatization. And in fact *this* is what your observation proves.
- Finally, it's worth pointing out that there are EF-style games which capture much different properties - specifically, elementary (or bounded elementary) equivalence for *logics other than first-order*. For example, consider the version of the EF-game where the game continues on for infinitely many moves; this captures elementary equivalence for the [infinitary logic $\mathcal{L}_{\infty\omega}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic), and when restricted to countable structures [captures isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Comment: I edited my post to ask you about something, please help me.

Comment: @Logic See my edit.

Comment: I've finished my edition.